# EB Garamond: \textfont6 is undefined with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, amsart, ebgaramond

I'm using `ebgaramond` font in `amsart` class. With `pdflatex`, everything works fine. However, when trying to typeset with `xelatex` or `lualatex`, I get multiple errors like `\textfont6 is undefined (character 40)`. It seems that this only happens if there're math symbols like `(`,`)`, `=` etc. in the abstract.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Below is a MWE.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{}

\begin{abstract}
    $(a=b)$
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

Some text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why LuaLaTeX is not able to get the proper font. However, since you're using a complete math font, you should load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{}

\begin{abstract}
    $(a=b)$
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

Some text $\sin x$ sin

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrike debugged further at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58324478#58324478

Answer (score 1):

I didn't trace it all but it's failing to set up the math fonts. You can encourage it to work by setting a discarded empty math list at begin document at normal size. (The issue appears when the first use of math is at a small size)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$ $}}
\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\date{}

\begin{abstract}
    $(a=b)$
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]